# Getting related data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables, something like this:

categories:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|  id           |   category_name    |
+---------------+--------------------+
|  1            |   Category 1       |
|  2            |   Category 2       |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

tasks:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
|  id           |   task_name               |   category_id   |
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
|  1            |   First task of the day   |       1         |
|  2            |   Then do this            |       1         |
+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
```

*This is a simplified version of my database, but you get the idea.*

I want to display the category as a title followed the tasks below, for example:

```
Category 1
   - First task of the day
   - Then do this

Category 2
   no tasks here :)
```

I'd be inclined to do something like this...

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");

foreach($query->result() as $cat){

    echo '<h1>'. $cat->category_name . '</h1>';

    $tasks_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE category_id='{$cat->id}'");

    foreach($tasks_query->result() as $task){
        echo $task->task_name;
    }
}
```

I know this would work, but it seems like it would be quite resource intensive with all those queries. So, I was wondering if this is the right way of doing this or is there a better, more efficient way. What would be the best practice way of doing this?

Hope all this makes sense.

Comment: Why not do a JOIN query? Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question. asking for a *best practice*,  will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Unless you're literally rendering to plain text output, you don't want to show the example you're showing in your question. Are you sure you want plain text?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't think the output is important at this stage. It will probably be a few DIVs, but will certainly be more complex that plain text. This was more a question about best practice, but it's apparent that this isn't the right place for this question.

Comment: it very much is, because your output determines whether a JOIN is appropriate or not.

Comment: Sure. Well like I said, I'm not entirely sure of the output yet, but it will be more than plain text.

Comment: A lot of "roundtrips" to and from the database can be relatively expensive, in terms of total elapsed time, especially if its a network connection... the database on one physical server, and the client on another physical server. Even if the network latency of a round trip is very small, the total amount of time starts to add up when we do thousands of roundtrips. And there's resources used on the database server for every statement execution (parsing the statement, generating execution plan, executing the plan, and preparing and returning the resultset.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers and help. I looked more into MySQL joins and this is what I come up with and it works!...

```
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT c.category_name, t.task_name
        FROM categories c
        INNER JOIN tasks t
        ON c.id = t.category_id");

    $categories = array();

    foreach($query->result() as $result)
    {

        if ( !in_array($result->category_name, $categories) )
        {
            $categories[] = $result->category_name;
            echo '<h3>' . $result->category_name . '</h3>';
        }

        echo "<div>" . $result->task_name . "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause on the query, there is no *guarantee* what order the rows will be returned in, MySQL is free to return them in any order it wants. If the rows are returned with the tasks from different categories interleaved, this will appear to be reporting some "tasks" under the wrong "category". Add an `ORDER BY` so the rows for the tasks under a given category will be "grouped" together.

Comment: The comment wasn't just for you, Lee. It was for the benefit of future readers who run across this question and answer. You may have added an ORDER BY where you needed it, but it's absent from this answer.

Comment: The code example in the original post would have returned a `category` and emitted a heading for it, even if there were no related tasks for it. (The example output showed "**`Category 2`**" and "**`no tasks here :)`**" under it. It's not clear whether that was meant as a task_name, or it represented a category that didn't have any tasks under it. To replicate the behavior of the original, I used an "outer join" in my example query.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right that there is some overhead with each query. The operations of sending the SQL text to the database server, the server parsing the statement for syntax, and then for semantics, developing an execution plan, then actually running the statement (obtaining locks, accessing blocks, releasing locks), preparing the resultset to send back to the client.  And on the client side, checking the status, and retrieving the result.

In terms of just the database, it is usually more efficient to run a single statement to return a single resultset. (There are cases when it isn't, such as when the large query is inefficient, like when the resultset is really, really big, and requires an expensive sort operation.)

Example of how to get the result in one statement:

```
SELECT c.category_name
     , t.task_name
  FROM categories c
  LEFT
  JOIN tasks t 
    ON t.category_id = c.id
 ORDER 
    BY c.category_name
     , t.task_name
```

The flip side of that is there is some "extra" work that needs to be one on the client to process that.

```
initialize a variable to hold "previous" category_name
loop fetching rows (until no more rows)
  if category_name is not equal to previous category_name
     emit category e.g. output "<h1>category_name"
     save new category_name as previous
  end if
  if task_name is not null
     emit task e.g. output "<br>task_name"
  end if
end loop
```

Comment: That's just an example, based on the queries in the question. We'd really want to return the integer `id` from category, and do the 'is the category  the same as the last one' check on the `id` rather than on a character string. The information from `category` will be duplicated for each `task` within the `category`. The example uses a "outer" join to return category which don't have any task, which is what the original queries would have done. When we have a choice between more or fewer "roundtrips" to the database, we usually opt for fewer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `join` in your SQL query it will put more of the burden on the database rather than the PHP engine (it'll be quicker and less resource-intensive, since you're running one query rather than many within a loop).

```
$query = $this->db->query(
                'SELECT *
                FROM tasks t
                    INNER JOIN categories c
                        ON t.category_id = c.id');

foreach ( $query->result() as $result) {
    echo $result->category_name . ' ' . $result->task_name;
}
```

Comment: Actually, running multiple statements against the database will put more of a burden on the database, than running a single statement does. In the vast majority of cases, a `JOIN` operation doesn't place a burden on the database, when the referenced tables are suitably indexed. (Obviously, we can construct a test case where it's less efficient, e.g. returning two thousand bytes from a single row from one table, and joining that with hundreds of thousands of rows from another table, creating a massive amount of "duplicated" data.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Maybe my statement was misleading, I didn't mean to say it would *place a burden on the database* necessarily, just that the database would be doing the work rather than the loops in the code, which would make it more efficient (generally). @szpal you're right, he probably needs to `select t.task_name, c.category_name` instead of `select *`

Comment: @anthony_mcdougle: Yes, the single statement against the database would actually be less overall work. We'd likely add an `ORDER BY category`, so the rows can be processed "in order" by the client, to make it easier to group the tasks, and detect the beginning of a new category, putting out a header for the new category (i.e. suppressing the display of category_name when it's a subsequent row for the same category.)